# jQuery .show()/.hide() causing the page to jump on click

Tags: jquery, events

**SEE THE SOLUTION TO THIS AND UPDATE BELOW:**

This is driving my crazy!!

```
    productTabAnchors.on('click', function (e) {
      var index = productTabLis.index($(this).parent());

      e.preventDefault();

      // switch all tabs off  
      productTabLis.removeClass('active');
      productTabAnchors.removeClass('active');
      productTabContent.removeClass('active').hide();

      // switch this tab on  
      $(this).addClass("active");
      productTabLis.eq(index).addClass('tab active');
      productTabContent.eq(index).addClass('active').show();
    });
```

`e.preventDefault()` does not seem to be working as the page jumps to the anchor. The anchor is nested in an `li`, so I've tried `e.stopPropagation` and `return false` too.

Why would this not work?

Here's a link to a fiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mayoung/4zs97/

Comment: Has the link been dynamically added?

Comment: Do you have any parse errors elsewhere on the page?

Comment: no other errors. it is being added dynamically, but .on is supposed to handle event binding for dynamically created elements. right?

Comment: What is the object **productTabAnchors** equal to?

Comment: @user699242 not the syntax you are using.. you should use delegated event methods..

Comment: productTabAnchors is a collection of anchors $('.product-tabs li a');

Comment: @Vega I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Turns out it may have had something to do with showing and hiding the elements. e.preventDefault was working, but the page was still jumping around when I clicked those elements. I believe that because the height of the hidden elements varied the window wasn't sure how to respond when those elements became visible.

Instead of display:none as the default, I used .hide() to hide the divs on page load, and then call .show(). Problem solved.

Here's a link to a fiddle demonstrating the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/mayoung/4zs97/

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have any parse errors elsewhere on the page?
>
> no other errors. it is being added dynamically, but .on is supposed to handle event binding for dynamically created elements. right?

You are using wrong `.on` syntax for handling dynamic elements.

What you need is

```
//v- Replace document with closest existing container on DOM ready
$(document).on('click', [selector], function() {
//                      ^-- replace with the dynamic element selector.
```

> productTabAnchors is a collection of anchors $('.product-tabs li a');

So in your case it should be,

```
$(document).on('click', '.product-tabs li a', function () {
```

or if .product-tabs exists on page load then,

```
$('.product-tabs').on('click', 'li a', function () {
```

Comment: you can use .on() two ways. The way you suggested and also the way that I'm doing it.

Comment: @user699242 The way you are using will work if `.product-tabs li a` exist when `productTabAnchors.on('click', function (e) {` line is executed. If it doesn't exist then `productTabAnchors.length` would be 0 which eventually will not bind the handler.

Comment: it does exist and the event handler is working just fine. it seems that e.preventDefault is working too, but the page still jumps.

Comment: @user699242 instead of `href="#"` use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: no dice with javascript:void() either. i don't know what the deal is. it really annoying though.

Answer (score 1):

It works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/B6Cmg/

What version of jQuery are you using? Make sure your version of jQuery supports **on()**

Comment: My version supports on. The click event is working just fine. The e.preventDefault is not.

Comment: Turns out, that it is working. It's not adding the # to the URL, but the page is still jumping to the anchor.